# A question on ring homomorphisms and maximal ideals.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $A,B$ be commutative rings, and let $\phi: A \to B$ be a ring homomorphism where $B$ has finitely many elements. Prove that if $I \subset B$ is a maximal ideal then $\phi^{-1}(I)$ is also a maximal ideal in $A$

I've tried to construct a proof by contradiction but with no success, im not looking for answers but rather hints.

Comment: Is commutativity assumed here?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes it is. Forgot to mention it.

Comment: Ok, I edited that assumption in. Feel free to insert such things as long as it doesn't wreck the work of someone who already answered.

Comment: What is "commutatximal"? I think you accidentally the question.

Comment: Yes I did, how to edit it back? @jef

Comment: Maybe from the edit history.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of thing screams "[isomorphism theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Rings)!"

We know $\phi(A)$ is a subring of $B$, and we'd like to talk about "$\phi(A)/I$" but unfortunately there's no guarantee $I\subseteq \phi(A)$. To overcome this, you can instead note that $S:=\phi(A)+I$ is a subring of $B$, and that $I\lhd S$, so $S/I$ is a ring, actually a subring of $B/I$.

$B/I$ is of course a field, and by assumption $B$ and $B/I$ are finite, so $B/I$ is a finite field. $S/I$, being a subring of a field, is a domain, and being a finite domain, [it's also a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem).

The second isomorphism theorem says that $S/I\cong \phi(A)/(\phi(A)\cap I)$. There is a very natural candidate for a surjective map $\psi:A\to \phi(A)/(\phi(A)\cap I)$. If you discover this map, you'll find its kernel is $\phi^{-1}(I)$.

Applying the first isomorphism theorem to $\psi$, this would prove $A/\phi^{-1}(I)$ is isomorphic to the field $S/I$, hence $\phi^{-1}(I)$ would be maximal in $A$. So there is only one thing left for you to do: can you see what $\psi$ should be?

Comment: Why is $B$ a field?

Comment: @GeorgeMouselli I corrected that typo, thanks. Of course it isn't necessarily a field, and that isn't anything we need anyhow.

Comment: I dont seem to understand, you are saying "$S$, being a subring of a field...". How is it a subring of a field, we just concluded that $B$ doesnt have to be a field.

Comment: @GeorgeMouselli Sorry. I think when I initially wrote this, I used $S$ for the quotient, rather than the subring of $B$, leading to these leftover typos. Try it again. We don't want S to be a domain, we want S/I to be a domain.

Comment: Thank you for correcting your errors. I think this was a ver nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: every subring of a finite field is also a finite field.

Same hint, more algebraic: if $x\notin \phi^{-1} (I)$, then multiplication by $x$ gives an injective map $A/\phi^{-1}(I) \to A/\phi^{-1}(I)$.

Comment: So you mean I should try to prove that $A/\phi^{-1}(I)$ is a subring of a finite field?

Comment: Yes, it has a natural map into a readily available one.

Comment: I dont even know if $A/\phi^{-1}(I)$ is finite, how can i observe that?

Comment: The problem gives you a maximal ideal, so it gives you a field.

Comment: @Sodan Now that rschwieb has let the cat out of the bag, I'll summarize this as follows: $A/\phi^{-1}(I)$ is naturally a subring of $B/I$, which is a finite field.  So if we can show that a subring of a finite field is a field, it follows that $\phi^{-1}(I)$ must be maximal.